# Returns the query result as a pure array (index array) instead of an associative array PHP Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

So I want to use `$this->db->where_not_in()` using an array in its second parameters.

I know it works fine if I have an index array and use it like this:

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_not_in('column', $names);
```

But the output array of my query looks like this, so I can't use this to the 2nd parameter `where_not_in ()`:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
      [id_question] => PN21022601
   )
   [1] => Array (
      [id_question] => PN21022602
   )
)
```

I tried to convert it to an index array using `array_values​​()` but it just returned the same result as above.

I've also read the documentation from [Codeigniter 3 here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#generating-query-results) by trying the `$query->result_array()` method, as well as the `$query->result()` method and the results are the same.

My expectation is that I can produce an array like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => PN21022601
   [1] => PN21022602
)
```

Did I miss something?
Is this an error from the mysql query I made? Especially at `group by` syntax?
Here is my query to generate data like the one above:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT e.id_pertanyaan
        
        FROM t_penilaian AS a
        JOIN t_penilaian_detail AS b ON a.id_penilaian = b.id_penilaian
        JOIN t_penilaian_detail_score AS c ON b.id_penilaian_detail = c.id_penilaian_detail
        JOIN m_pertanyaan_detail AS d ON c.id_pertanyaan_detail = d.id_pertanyaan_detail
        JOIN m_pertanyaan AS e ON d.id_pertanyaan = e.id_pertanyaan
        
        WHERE a.id_user = '$id_user'
        GROUP BY e.id_pertanyaan");
```

This is an [example script](https://www.codepile.net/pile/XaPLR0aK) for creating the database.
and [DB Designer](https://dbdesigner.page.link/jtPAmiEfakzPgcdXA) to quickly see the relationship

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Please dont show us pictures of code!! If its text then post it as text into your question, formatted. We cannot copy/paste from a picture and search engines cannot index code-pitures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se your query to return array like so:

```
$results = $this->db->result_array();
```

Having the results as array instead of object you can get just one of the columns as a normal array with array column.

```
$results = array_column($this->db->result_array(), 'id_question');
```

This way the results will be exactly like you want.

More info about array column here:

Answer (score 1):

you can use php funcs like array_map for this specific case:

```
$newArr = array_map(function($val){
    return $val['id_question'];
},$results);
```

this should give you the required result

Comment: Ok I tried it so `$val` contains `$query->result_array()` right?
I got an error `Undefined variable: results`, what should `$results` contain?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Wrong. `$results` is the array you're mapping. `$val` is every individual value from it. When you don't understand a function, read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: Also, this is essentially a roundabout way to do [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column).

Comment: @El_Vanja I didn't use the answer above, but tried to use `array_column()` as you said and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @El_Vanja I didn't knew about this function. thank for the lesson.